# crontab: task not running in my crontab entry

Tags: cron

I have problem with crontab because my crontab entry not running

```
$ date
Tue Jan  6 07:21:11

$ crontab -l
*/2 6-11 * * 1-3 hostnamectl >> /home/bob/hostsname.txt
```

this crontab should be running every 2 minutes from 6-11 AM every monday - weds, but nothing happened. record in /var/log/cron for this cronjobs is empty

i debug to ensure crond is running and change to below

```
* * * * * hostnamectl >> /home/bob/hostsname_debug.txt
```

cronjobs running as expected every 1 minutes. i see hostsname_debug.txt in home directory.
i see the log in /var/log/cron

why the first cronjobs not running?

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com would be a better place for this.

Comment: It looks fine to me. Are you sure you're using a modern version of `cron` that understands `*/2`?

Comment: I am using CentOS 7, this my cron version crontabs-1.11-6.20121102git.el7.noarch. how to move this question to unix.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Does it work if you use `0,2,4,6,8,...58`?

Comment: yes, working, i try * all or 2 * * * * or * 6-11 * * 1-3, all working

Comment: Sounds like it just doesn't support the `/` format. What does the man page say?

Comment: man pages said i can use /. just now i try to restart this machine and now this job is running. don't know what is the problem before. thank you barmar.

Comment: Maybe you didn't install the crontab properly with `crontab -e`.